# Issue while implementing Entity Framework 6.0 in VS 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

While implementing Entity Framework 6.0 in VS 2012 (i.e. creating edmx file & tried to generate my Model class out of it), I got below error message (even though Test Connection to DB is succeeding).

The 'SqlStudio Profile Package' package did not load correctly

As a resolution step I tried to re install “Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework"
but to my surprise I could not find this item in the installed items in Programs & Feature.

Any fix is higly appreciated, as I dont want to re install either my VS 2012 or SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the data-tier framework from scratch> downloadable from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39301)

If you have, then try deleting the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache** file from

**C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache**

You can also try deleting the

**C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0**

and

**C:\Users\<>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0**

folders but this will mean you'll lose your VS configuration.

Comment: I did all the step mentioned by you, but it has not fixed my problem... Now I m going to re install VS 2012 & SQL 2008. Can you help me if only re installation of VS 2012 is sufficient?

Comment: Hope this isn't too late. Others have suggested that you may be able to run a repair on SQL rather than a reinstall to resolve...